# Is there a way to configure bitcoind to be nicer about its harddrive bandwidth usage?

Tags: bitcoind

I'm running bitcoind and its using literally 100% of my primary SDD's throughput. This is making my computer run very slowly in some cases (eg saving files is absurdly slow). Is there a way to configure it to only us maybe 95% of the available throughput at max so other stuff can get through?

OS: Windows

Comment: This is [not possible](https://superuser.com/questions/795483/how-to-limit-hdd-write-speed-for-chosen-programs). Writing to disk is handled by kernel/OS, not by programs.

Comment: This is [possible](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice). Could you give more information about your operating system?

Comment: @NickODell Windows (updated OP)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to configure bitcoin to self-limit.

That said, Windows has an IO scheduler, which shares read/write bandwidth between processes. You can tell this IO scheduler to deprioritize a specific process. This isn't directly accessible from Task Manager or Process Explorer, but there are two third-party programs, called [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/) and [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) which are capable of changing this.

([Source.](https://superuser.com/questions/136021/how-to-change-i-o-priority-of-a-process-or-thread-in-win7))

(I think your problem is more likely to be a CPU bottleneck than IO, but you asked for this approach, and I assume you have a good reason.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this out! Disk usage us up at 100%, CPU is usage is hovering between 10-25% (maxing one core).